# Simple batch file not executing?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line, command

I'm trying to merge txt files in a dir using the following

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\textfiles\
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> C:\Users\Desktop\output.txt
```

But I am not getting any output (because last line I'm pretty sure) , can anyone help me out here?

Also how can I make the output filename automatically append text or date for the date e.g. output_random.txt or output_19.06.14.txt ?

Edited code (thanks to Stephan) but not appending date:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\TextFiles"
for /f %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%i
set dt=%dt:~0,8%
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> C:\TextFiles\output-%dt%.txt
```

Comment: Also `copy c:\textfiles\*.txt C:\Users\Desktop\output.txt` is probably more straightforward. See `copy /?`.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks this seems a lot more straightforward although I wonder what the differences are? none?

Comment: You you were just doing it the hard way. Of course copy isn't flexible while for loops are. Also `forfiles` (`forfiles/?`) is meant to replace `for` lops for simple things like this (and other common uses of `for`). FOR loops are ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside batchfiles, you have to use `%%f` instead of `%f`, which works on commandline only:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> C:\Users\Desktop\output.txt
```

for the "Random or Date" part:

As you say "random or date", I assume, the date don't have to have a specific format. Best way (because independent of locale settings) would be:

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%i
set dt=%dt:~0,8%
```

`%dt%` will be in the format YYYYMMDD.
You can easily add the time with `set dt=%dt:~0,14%` (YYYYMMDDhhmmss) and output to `...output-%dt%.txt`

for formatting `%dt%` to DD-MM-YYYY:

```
set dt=%dt:~6,2%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~0,4%
```

Extended Reading - [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks a lot, the merge function is working now! One problem though is the date is not appending to the output file. I have edited my top post to show my current code. Can you also tell me how I can get the date format into DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: What do you mean with "not appending to the outputfile"? "Appending to the filename" or "writing it into the file contents"?  For formatting the date, see my edit.

Comment: Not appending as in I set output file as C:\TextFiles\output-%dt%.txt but the actual file that is outputted is "output.txt"

Comment: Hey, I just tried your DD-MM-YYYY formatting for date and now it works! I think the previous date formatting (dt) may have been not correct? either way it now works and thank you very much, Stephan! :)